# Sphinx search output

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have installed and testing out the sphinx search, i am getting a notice: undefined index id @ line 37... please find below my code... also, I want to print the results any help in that area is also much appreciated

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';
include 'sphinxapi.php';
$no=0;  
$cl = new SphinxClient;  
$cl->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);  
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);  
$cl->SetLimits(0, 25);  
//Sorts by relevance in descending order (best matches first)  
$cl->SetSortMode (SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE); //"published asc/desc"  
//Insert here text for searching  
$q = '"' . $cl->EscapeString($_GET['q']) . '"/1';
$res = $cl->Query($q, 'resume');  

if ( $res===false )
{
    print "Query failed: " . $cl->GetLastError() . ".\n";

} else
{
    if ( $cl->GetLastWarning() )
        print "WARNING: " . $cl->GetLastWarning() . "\n\n";

    print "Query '$q' retrieved $res[total] of $res[total_found] matches in $res[time] sec.\n";
    print "Query stats:\n";
    if ( is_array($res["words"]) )
        foreach ( $res["words"] as $word => $info )
            print "    '$word' found $info[hits] times in $info[docs] documents\n";
    print "\n";

    if ( is_array($res["matches"]) )
    {
        $n = 1;
        print "Matches:\n";
        foreach ( $res["matches"] as $docinfo )
        {
    Line37==>   print "$n. doc_id=$docinfo[id], weight=$docinfo[weight]";
            foreach ( $res["attrs"] as $attrname => $attrtype )
            {
                $value = $docinfo["attrs"][$attrname];
                if ( $attrtype==SPH_ATTR_MULTI || $attrtype==SPH_ATTR_MULTI64 )
                {
                    $value = "(" . join ( ",", $value ) .")";
                } else
                {
                    if ( $attrtype==SPH_ATTR_TIMESTAMP )
                        $value = date ( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $value );
                }
                print ", $attrname=$value";
            }
            print "\n";
            $n++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line is 37? I don't think anyone wants to count.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn sorry, I forgot to add that, I just edited the code also pasting the line 37 here, Line37==>   print "$n. doc_id=$docinfo[id], weight=$docinfo[weight]";

Comment: Did You have defined index 'resume' in Your sphinxsearch.conf ? Here is used $res = $cl->Query($q, 'resume');

Comment: @ryrysz I did, it fetches out the results but with the Noitce message of an undefined index 'id'

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood, it's standard php notice. Please dump Your $docinfo variable for every iteration, is ID avaiable ?. (before line 37, add var_dump($docinfo)). First element of $docinfo should be ID.
When you build an index, have You some warnings / errors?

Answer (score 0):

By default there **wont** be a [id] value in the $matches array. The id is stored as the key of the array.

ie would do

```
foreach ( $res["matches"] as $id => $docinfo )
```

---

To get a numeric array, with a [id] value, need to use `->SetArrayResult(true)`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setarrayresult

Comment: tried your suggestion but it still spitting out the php notice error.

Comment: did you change line 37 too?

Comment: well if you change the foreach, so have the id available. no longer look for it in docinfo

Comment: Thanks a lot, It did helped. Now I am focusing on printing out the results using the $id variable, any suggestions would be much appreciated.